# Fedora 35 gnome-x11 incomplete environment variables

Tags: bash, gnome, environment-variables, login

For unrelated reasons (XWayland crashing the Bash too often with applications like gnuplot, firefox...) I'm trying to start the "Gnome on X11" when login into my Fedora 35 laptop. This is basically done by typing my user name into the login-screen and  selecting not the default GNOME but the alternative GNOME on X11 and the continuing by typing the password.

The problem is: when the "Activities" and "xterm" are selected this ends up in a Bash-shell where `$HOME` is set to `/root`, where I expect to have `/home/$USER`, and none of `.login`, `.bashrc` or `.bash-login` seem to be executed. [No such incomplete setup is seen for the Wayland-gnome.] The xdg environment variables are set as expected

```
XDG_MENU_PREFIX=gnome-
XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP=gnome-xorg
XDG_SESSION_TYPE=x11
XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=GNOME
XDG_SESSION_CLASS=user
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
```

The file `/etc/environment` is empty.
The question is: how to I get the default behaviour for gnome-x11 bash environment initialization on Fedora 35?

- The same behaviour happens when a `gnome-terminal` is started instead of a `xterm`
- `/etc/passwd` contains the correct home directory
- The `/usr/bin/gnome-session` script starts a shell named by $SHELL only if the session is a wayland session. Is this restriction intended?
- `/usr/share/applications/xterm.desktop` looks alright and does not seem to care about `$HOME`
- There is no setting of `HOME` in any of the `/etc/gdm` directories.
- There is no setting of `HOME` in any of the `/etc/X11` directories.
- There is no setting of `HOME` in any of the `/etc/profile.d` directories.
- There is no `.gdmrc` in my (correct) `$HOME` directory.
- The same problem exists on `Fedora 34`

Comment: I'm not on Fedora 35 yet, but `gnome` on `X11` works fine for me on a previous Fedora version. My `xterm` launch works but I almost always use `gnome-terminal`. Does your `/usr/share/applications/xterm.desktop` look normal?